# REST And Can Delete/Update etc actions

Tags: json, rest, api

I am writing a REST API. However, one of the requirements is to allow the caller to determine if an action may be performed (so that, for example, a button can be enabled or disabled, etc.)
The action might not be allowed for several reasons - perhaps user permissions, but possibly because, for example, you can't delete a shared object, or you can't create an item with the same name as another item or an array of other business rules.
All the logic to determine *if* something can be deleted should be determined in the back end, but the front end must show this in the GUI.

I am trying to find the right pattern to use for this in REST, and am coming up a bit short. I could create a parallel API so for every entity endpoint there was an EntityPermissions endpoint, but that seems to be overkill. I could also do something like add an HTTP header that indicates that the request was only to check permisisons, not perform it, but that seems a bit dubious, and likely to mess up the http cache.

Can anyone point me to the common pattern for doing something like this? Does it have a name? Or a web page that discusses it? I'm sure everyone has their own ideas on this (like my dumb ideas) but I this seems to be a common enough requirement that I figure there must be a common pattern for it. But google didn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

There's going to be multiple opinionated answers about this. I'll share mine. Might not be the best for your problem, but it's a valid solutions.

If you followed the real definition of REST, you would be building a hypermedia/HATEOAS-style webservice. Urls would not be hardcoded, they would be discovered and actions would be discovered by the existence of a link.

If an action may not be performed, you can just hide the link. If a user fetches the next resource they just see all the available actions right there.

A popular format for hypermedia API's is [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html). You might decorate the links further with more information from [HTTP Link hints](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-link-hint-01).

If this is the first time you heard of hypermedia API's, there might be a bit of a learning curve. The results of learning this can be very beneficial though.